# Representation theory and simultaneous block diagonalization of matrices with common symmetries

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, diagonalization

Group representation theory has applications in a lot of areas and problems in mathematics, one of such an example is the finest simultaneous block diagonalization of the set of matrices with common symmetries. According to Page 7 of [this paper](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/43911551/star1MKKK.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1490395512&Signature=VhxhWlA%2BEjjBb7bBQdXu4OhcQcM%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DA_Numerical_Algorithm_for_Block-Diagonal.pdf), let $\{T(g)\}$ be an orthogonal matrix representation of a group $G$, if a set of matrices $\{A_p\}$ all share the symmetry described by $G$, that is,

$T(g)^\intercal A_p T(g) = A_p, \ \forall g\in G \ \text{and} \ \forall p,$

then a simultaneous block diagonalization of $A_p$ can be obtained through the decomposition of the representation $\{T(g)\}$ into irreducible representations. In particular, if $\{P^\intercal T(g) P\}$ is the direct sum of irreducible representations with dimensions $n_i$ and multiplicities $m_i$, then each element in $\{P^\intercal A_p P\}$ has a common block structure as the direct sum of blocks of dimensions $m_i$ and multiplicities $n_i$.

Can anyone point me to references/theorems in group representation theory from which this claim is based? Thanks!

Comment: Schur's Lemma has something to say. BTW, your reference gives me an error message.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for pointing it out, it seems the link only works on laptop and fails on mobile app. Here is the title of the paper 'A numerical algorithm for block-diagonal decomposition of matrix-algebras with application to semidefinite programming'.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes I agree Schur's Lemma is involved. It applies to cases when the multiplicity of the irreducible representations are one, since any matrix that commutes with all matrices in an irreducible representation must be the identity matrix times a constant. What I do not see yet is how to generalize this to cases with multiplicities larger than one.

Comment: No, it does a lot more than that. If you  suppose $T$ is already in block form with the irreducibles along the diagonal , and then put $A$ into the same blocks, Schur will give that the blocks corr to places where there are different irreducibles are $O$ (as you've seen) and the other blocks are diagonal matrices, If you re-order the bases you'll see there are $n_i$ and dimension is $m_i$. All this over $\mathbb{C}$ at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I am sure that there is a slicker way of serving this up, and will happily delete this when it emerges. This is just the old-fashioned matrix way of looking at things.]

Suppose $T$ is a representation of the finite groups $G$ on the finite-dimensional space $V$. That is the same as saying that $V$ is a $\mathbb{C}G$-module. By Mashke's Theorem we can write $V=V_1\oplus\dots\oplus V_m$ where the $V_i$ are irreducibles. Let $\alpha:V\to V$ commute with all the $T(g)$.

Choose a basis of $V$ compatible with this decomposition. Then in terms of block matrices we have that 
$$
T(g)=\left[\begin{matrix}
T_1(g) & 0 & \dots &0\\
0    &T_2(g) &\dots& 0\\
0   & 0 & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0& \dots &T_m(g)\\
\end{matrix}
\right],
\ \ \ 
A=\left[\begin{matrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & \dots &A_{1m}\\
A_{21} & A_{22} & \dots &A_{2m}\\
\vdots &\vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
A_{m1} & A_{m2}& \dots &A_{mm}\\
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$

The hypothesis of commutativity now gives $T_{r}(g)A_{rs}=A_{rs}T_{s}(g)$. As the $V_i$ are irreducible, Schur's Lemma yields that $A_{rs}=O$ whenever $V_r$ and $V_s$ are not isomorphic, and $A_{rs}=\lambda_{rs} I$ ($\lambda_{rs}\in\mathbb{C}$) when they are isomorphic.

If we now group the $V_i$ into "clumps" of isomorphic modules, we have that both $T(g)$ and $A$ are in diagonal block form; both havezeros where the row and column correspond to non-isomorphic modules.

That means that we need only  consider the case when $V=V_1\oplus\dots\oplus V_m$ is the direct sum of isomorphic irreducibles. What we have proved in this case is that $A=\Lambda \otimes I_n$, where $n$ is the vector space dimension of $V_1$, and $\Lambda$ is the $m\times m$ matrix of the $\lambda_{rs}$.